# How to call a service from Main application calls Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm building a Spring Boot application that will be called from command line.
I will pass to application some parameters but I'm having problems to call a service from this class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);

        App app = new App();
        app.myMethod();    
    }

    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    private void myMethod(){
        myService.save();
    }
}
```

I'm trying to call a method from inside the main but I'm getting the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.ef.Parser.App.myMethod(Application.java:26)
at com.ef.Parser.App.main(Application.java:18)
```

Comment: the instance you are creating in the main is not the same instance springboot instantiates; you could remove those lines in main, and ad a `@PostContruct` annotation on top of myMethod() instead

Answer (score 43, accepted):

you can create a class that implements CommandLineRunner and this will be invoked after the app will start

```
@Component
public class CommandLineAppStartupRunner implements CommandLineRunner {
    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    @Override
    public void run(String...args) throws Exception {
       myService.save();

    }
}
```

you can get farther information on this [here](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-applicationrunner-and-commandlinerunne)

Comment: Worked! Thanks :D

Comment: Is there a way to call the method from terminal? I mean the save () method.

Comment: @ken4ward, basically there isn't a direct way to call a specific function inside the entire application, without calling the whole application... you can work around that with many of spring features like profiles, conditional classes and env variables, what is your use case exactly?

Answer (score 51):

In SpringBoot 2.x you can simply run the application by `SpringApplication.run` method and operate on the returned ApplicationContext. Complete example below:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import java.util.Arrays;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
        SomeService service = applicationContext.getBean(SomeService.class);
        service.doSth(args);
    }
}

@Service
class SomeService {

    public void doSth(String[] args){
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(args));
    }
}
```

Comment: save my night :)

Answer (score 6):

By using the `new` keyword yourself to create an instance of the `App` class, Spring cannot know about it.

It's also redundant, as Spring automatically creates a bean instance of this class by a mechanism called component scan.

I like the solution of the `CommandLineRunner`.

What you also can do, is retrieve the `ApplicationContext`, lookup the bean and then call the method.

You can inject the `ApplicationContext` by letting your `App` class implement `ApplicationContextAware`, override the setter method and save the context in a static variable which you can access from your main method.

Then, you can use it to retrieve the correct `App` instance.

```
App myApp = (App) applicationContext.getBean(App.class);
myApp.myMethod()
```

Please note that accessing the `ApplicationContext` directly does kind of violate the whole dependency injection principle, but sometimes you haven't got much choice.

Answer (score 2):

The issue with your code is you didn't look up the applicationContext bean for the service Which you are using. I had a similar use case, to call a feature service on the startup of the application. Initializing multiple applicationContext beans for the services and then making the method called works just fine! Code below :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(UamRbacApplication.class, args);
    AccessChangeSchedulerService accessChangeSchedulerService = applicationContext.getBean(AccessChangeSchedulerService.class);
    AppContext appContext = applicationContext.getBean(AppContext.class);
    try {
        accessChangeSchedulerService.fetchAccessLevelChanges("EP", appContext.getSplunkToken());
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Cheers.