# How to call Java HTTP POST method in Angular

Tags: java, angular, spring, http, mybatis

I have the following problem: I created a Java project using Spring boot and MyBatis, I have some classes (for example DirezioneRegionale), with his mapper interface for MyBatis (with the correspondant XML file), his service class and a controller.
I tested the HTTP calls and they works (I'm able to see the result of my queries and they are correct).

You can see how I implemented the Java and MyBatis part here: [Return a List<MyClass> in MyBatis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60400672/return-a-listmyclass-in-mybatis)

Now the problem is that this is part of a greater project, in which i use Angular 8, I should be able to call the HTTP POST method and to have returned, using JSON I suppose, the equivalent of my Java class but in TypeScript.

To do that I have tried the following thing:

In the app.component.ts I have added:

```
allDirReg = this.piuService.getAllDirReg();
```

In the app.component.html I have added:

```
<p>{{ allDirReg }}</p>
```

So I expected to have returned a list with the id values and description values of my DirezioneRegionale object, but only

```
[object Object]
```

appears.

I even tried to change, in the app.component.ts file, the line in this way:

```
allDirReg = JSON.stringify(this.piuService.getAllDirReg());
```

But the result is:

```
{
   "_isScalar": false,
   "source": {
      "_isScalar": false,
      "source": {
         "_isScalar": false,
         "source": {
            "_isScalar": true,
            "value": {
               "url": "localhost:8081/getAllDirRegs",
               "body": null,
               "reportProgress": false,
               "withCredentials": false,
               "responseType": "json",
               "method": "POST",
               "headers": {
                  "normalizedNames": {},
                  "lazyUpdate": null,
                  "headers": {}
               },
               "params": {
                  "updates": null,
                  "cloneFrom": null,
                  "encoder": {},
                  "map": null
               },
               "urlWithParams": "localhost:8081/getAllDirRegs"
            }
         },
         "operator": {
            "concurrent":1
         }
      },
      "operator": {}
   },
   "operator": {}
}
```

my service's code in Angular is the following:

```
  getAllDirReg() {
    const doneCallback = this.loadingService.startLoading();
    return this.http.post<any>(`localhost:8081/getAllDirRegs`, {}).pipe(finalize(doneCallback))
  }
```

**EDIT:**
This is my Java DirezioneRegionaleController:

```
@RestController
public class DirezioneRegionaleController {

    @Autowired
    private DirezioneRegionaleService direzioneRegionaleService;

    @PostMapping("getAllDirRegs")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<?> getAllDirRegs() {
        List<DirezioneRegionale> allDirRegs = direzioneRegionaleService.getAllDirRegs();
        if (null == allDirRegs) {
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        }

        List<JSONObject> allDirRegsJSON = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
        for (DirezioneRegionale dr : allDirRegs) {
            JSONObject drJSON = new JSONObject();
            drJSON.put("id", dr.getID());
            drJSON.put("description", dr.getDescription());
            allDirRegsJSON.add(drJSON);
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<List<JSONObject>>(allDirRegsJSON, HttpStatus.OK);

        // return ResponseEntity.ok(allDirRegs);
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

What I expect to be returned:

```
[{"description":"DIR REG CAMPAN BASIL CALABR PUGLIA","direzioniCommerciali":null,"id":"09560"},{"description":"DBT DIREZIONE MILANO E PROVINCIA","direzioniCommerciali":null,"id":"09546"},{"description":"DBT DIR V FVG TR AA","direzioniCommerciali":null,"id":"09547"},{"description":"DBT DIR MILANO E PROVINCIA","direzioniCommerciali":null,"id":"09546"},{"description":"DR EM RO MAR ABR MOL","direzioniCommerciali":null,"id":"09548"},{"description":"DBT DIR V FVG  TR AA","direzioniCommerciali":null,"id":"09547"},{"description":"DBT DIREZIONE PIEMONTE V D'AOSTA LIGURIA","direzioniCommerciali":null,"id":"09544"},{"description":"DR FINAN INST","direzioniCommerciali":null,"id":"11471"},{"description":"DIREZIONE RETE SANPAOLO","direzioniCommerciali":null,"id":"00FIT"},{"description":"DR CAM BA CAL PU SIC","direzioniCommerciali":null,"id":"09560"},{"description":"DIR.GEN.BANCA APULIA","direzioniCommerciali":null,"id":"00FIT"},{"description":"DR TOSC UMB LAZ SARD","direzioniCommerciali":null,"id":"09549"},{"description":"DIREZIONE GENERALE -  BANCO DI NAPOLI","direzioniCommerciali":null,"id":"00FIT"},{"description":"COORDINAMENTO SERVIZIO GESTORE REMOTO","direzioniCommerciali":null,"id":"20233"},{"description":"DBT DIREZIONE LOMBARDIA","direzioniCommerciali":null,"id":"09545"},{"description":"DIREZIONE GENERALE","direzioniCommerciali":null,"id":"00FIT"},{"description":"DBT DIR CAMP BASIL CAL E PUG","direzioniCommerciali":null,"id":"09560"},{"description":"DBT DIR VEN FVG E TR AA","direzioniCommerciali":null,"id":"09547"},{"description":"DBT DIR MI E PROV","direzioniCommerciali":null,"id":"09546"},{"description":"DIR REG TOSCANA E UMBRIA","direzioniCommerciali":null,"id":"09549"},{"description":"DIR REG LAZIO SARDEGNA E SICILIA","direzioniCommerciali":null,"id":"09590"},{"description":"DIREZIONE GENERALE CRFORLI' E ROMAGNA","direzioniCommerciali":null,"id":"00FIT"},{"description":"DR CAM BA CAL PU","direzioniCommerciali":null,"id":"09560"},{"description":"DR GLOBAL CORPORATE","direzioniCommerciali":null,"id":"11474"},{"description":"DR TOS UMB LAZ E SAR","direzioniCommerciali":null,"id":"09549"},{"description":"D.R.CA.BA.CAL.PU.","direzioniCommerciali":null,"id":"09560"},{"description":"DBT DIREZIONE VEN FRIULI VG E TRENTIN AA","direzioniCommerciali":null,"id":"09547"},{"description":"DR TOS E UMB","direzioniCommerciali":null,"id":"09549"},{"description":"DIREZ. S. PAOLO B.CO DI NAPOLI","direzioniCommerciali":null,"id":"00FIT"},{"description":"DR GLOB CORP","direzioniCommerciali":null,"id":"11474"},{"description":"DBT DIR PIEM VAL D'AOS E LIG","direzioniCommerciali":null,"id":"09544"},{"description":"DIR REG EMILIA R,MARCHE,ABRUZZO,MOLISE","direzioniCommerciali":null,"id":"09548"},{"description":"DIREZIONE GENERALE CARISBO","direzioniCommerciali":null,"id":"00FIT"},{"description":"DBT DIR PIEM VDA LIG","direzioniCommerciali":null,"id":"09544"},{"description":"DBT DIR EMIL MAR ABR E MOL","direzioniCommerciali":null,"id":"09548"},{"description":"DIREZIONE GENERALE CR VENETO","direzioniCommerciali":null,"id":"00FIT"},{"description":"DIREZIONE GENERALE CR FVG","direzioniCommerciali":null,"id":"00FIT"},{"description":"DR LAZIO SAR E SIC","direzioniCommerciali":null,"id":"09590"},{"description":"DBT DIR LOMBARDIA","direzioniCommerciali":null,"id":"09545"}]
```

**EDIT 3:**
My app.component.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})

export class AppComponent {
  constructor(
    private piuService: PiuService) {
  }
  title = "PIU Versione 2";

  allDirReg = this.piuService.getAllDirReg().subscribe(bodyRes => { this.allDirReg = JSON.stringify(bodyRes)})

}
```

Comment: Can you please show the actual response of the server?

Answer (score 1):

The JSON you see there, is the structure of the `Observable` class

`HttpClient.post` method returns an `Observable<T>` on which you have to call the `subscribe` method to be able to treat the server response once you received it. It's an asynchronous mechanism.

example:

```
...
this.piuService.getAllDirReg().subscribe(bodyRes=> { this.allDirReg = bodyRes });
...
```

this is to access the response body, but you can access response itself. Take a look at HttpClient methods definitions. You can provide some options to get what you want.

EDIT: As you didn't provide options to the post method, I assumed that the default `observe` option was the HttpResponse. It seems that its the body itself. I've edited the example in consquences.

EDIT2: After seeing your component class, some things are wrong there. Version that should work:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private piuService: PiuService) {
  }
  title = "PIU Versione 2";
  allDirReg = "";

  ngOnInit() {
    this.piuService.getAllDirReg().subscribe(bodyRes => { this.allDirReg = JSON.stringify(bodyRes)})
  }
}
```

But in this case you work with a stringified model, which is not the main goal. You should use defined class models when working with TS and Angular. I suggest you to follow an Angular tutorial. You can try with Tour of Heroes which is the Google's introduction tutorial to Angular.

Comment: If I do in this way I have this error: "TS2663: Cannot find name 'allDirReg'. Did you mean the instance member 'this.allDirReg'?"
If I substitute allDirReg with this.allDirReg and then stringify I have nothing printed on my browser, without stringify I have the same "[object Object]" response

Comment: Yes.. my mistake, use `this.allDirReg`. Can you try with: `this.piuService.getAllDirReg().subscribe(bodyRes => { this.allDirReg = JSON.stringify(bodyRes) });`

Comment: Now the IDE says: TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Subscription'.

Comment: Can you edit your post and show your app.component.ts? hard to tell what's wrong without the code

Comment: Edited, it gives me error both in this way or if I declare allDirReg before or when I just write this... without declaration

Comment: @antoninus96 Edited my answer. You should follow some tutorial, there's basic concepts that you need to understand when working with TS or Angular. The example I gave does not follow best practices. No types, working with JSON string instead of view models, etc.. I've followed your case but if you're learning angular, you're going in a wrong way

Comment: Yes, I known, I started few days ago to use Angular but I have to do a project for work. Now I have another problem, when i serve I have this error: ERROR 
Object { headers: {…}, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "localhost:8081/getAllDirRegs", ok: false, name: "HttpErrorResponse", message: "Http failure response for localhost:8081/getAllDirRegs: 0 Unknown Error", error: error }  Do you know what could it be?

Comment: It is the same both for POST or GET requestes, I tried both

Comment: Maybe there's more informations in server side logs (Exceptions or something else). What you gave there is not useful. As the main problem has been resolved (client's request -> retrieval of the server's response) you should open a new post dedicated to this new issue.