# Spring jdbcTemplate NPE exception

Tags: spring, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am trying to use the jdbcTemplate to query a MySQL database to get the SYSDATE. So the query is as simple as `SELECT SYSDATE()`

However, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.trade.xml.modifier.Test.<init>(Test.java:18)
at com.trade.xml.modifier.TradeModifierApplication.main(TradeModifierApplication.java:17)
```

Here is a bit of what I do:

1. I created a `DatabaseConfiguration.class` which should take all the connection details from the `application.properties`

The `application.properties` looks like this:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xmlconverter
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDBDialect
```

The `DatabaseConfiguration.class` looks like this

```
@Configuration
public class DatabaseConfiguration {

        @Value("${spring.datasource.driver-class-name}")
        private String driverName;

        @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
        private String url;

        @Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
        private String userName;

        @Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
        private String password;

        @Bean(name = "dataSource")
        public DataSource dataSource() {
            final DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
            dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverName);
            dataSource.setUrl(url);
            dataSource.setUsername(userName);
            dataSource.setPassword(password);
            return dataSource;
        }
    
    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate dbjdbcTemplate() {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource());
    }

}
```

2.I also created a `Test.class` where I wrote my method for querying

```
@Service
public class Test {
    
    //Since a bean is created in DatabaseConfiguration, 
    //"template = new JdbcTemplate()" is omitted (should be recognized automatically, right?)
    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate template;
    
    
    public String getDate() {
        String sql = "SELECT SYSDATE()";
        
        return template.queryForObject(sql, String.class);
    }

}
```

3. The main class looks as follows

   ```
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class TradeModifierApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TradeModifierApplication.class, args);

        Test test = new Test();
        System.out.println(test.getDate());
   ```

At this point I have read the whole Internet and I am not sure what is the root cause of this NPE. Any help/hints will be appreciated.

Comment: In your debugger is `template` wired?, as in it's not a null and spring constructed it

Comment: Are those classes in different packages? If they are then you need to declare @ComponentScan with specific packages

Comment: @CholNhial yes, so the problem comes when the return statement in Test is executed

Comment: @devwebcl Yes, everything is in the same package for now just so I understand how it works

Comment: @Ne7WoRK change your data type from String to LocalDateTime on `queryForObject`

Comment: @CholNhial Yes, when I executed it from phpMyAdmin (since I am using XAMPP) it works as a charm from there

Comment: Sorry I deleted that comment it wasn't relevant. So try what I just said. There's a type mismatch.

Comment: @CholNhial Thanks for the hint, but that did not solve it.

Comment: do you have `template.queryForObject(sql, LocalDateTime.class);` and you also need to change the return type

Comment: @CholNhial Haha, I am not that newbie. Yes, I changed them both

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226332/discussion-between-chol-nhial-and-ne7work).

Answer (score 0):

The problem should be this line in TradeModifierApplication:

```
Test test = new Test();
```

You should let the spring container to instance Test class.

One way would be to inject by:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(TradeModifierApplication.class, args);
    Test service = applicationContext.getBean(Test.class);
    service.getDate());
}
```

}

Comment: Maybe you are right, but then how to print the result of the query in the console ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49698963/how-to-call-a-service-from-main-application-calls-spring-boot

Comment: SomeService service = applicationContext.getBean(SomeService.class);
        service.doSth(args);

Comment: Still the same error....